# How to send 'this' as variable

Tags: java, android

I have to send `this` to another class
I need void in my activity like this:

```
mStrawberry.foo(this)
```

and inside Strawberry

```
public class Strawberry{

    public Strawberry(){}

    foo( ????? thisVariable ){
     //work with this...
    }

}
```

I know this is MainActivity.this bud I have to use different class not only MainActivity...

Thank you for the reply

Comment: *"I know this is MainActivity.this bud I have to use different class not only MainActivity..."* What do you mean by that?

Comment: `foo(Activity thisVariable)` ?

Comment: do you want to send different objects there or just one type?

Comment: Hint: your problem seems to be ... that you have absolutely **no clue** of the Java programming language. But yet you decided to start learning that by directly jumping into the "Android" thing. Seriously: don't do that. Step back for some weeks, and learn the java basics. And then, when you are somehow confident, then move forward. Otherwise, your experiments with Android programming will be mainly frustrating and leading nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a parameter of the appropriate type (whatever `this` is in the code `mStrawberry.foo(this)`):

```
public class Strawberry{

    public Strawberry(){}

    foo(TheRelevantType thisVariable ){ // ***
         thisVariable.doSomething();    // ***
    }

}
```

In the above, I've used `TheRelevantType`.

> I know this is MainActivity.this bud I have to use different class not only MainActivity...

If you need to have a method that accepts instances of two different classes, you do that by having both classes implement an interface with the common aspects you need to use:

```
interface ActivityCommon {
    void doSomething();
}

class ThisActivity implements ActivityCommon {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is ThisActivity's doSomething");
    }
}

class ThatActivity implements ActivityCommon {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is ThatActivity's doSomething");
    }
}

class Strawberry {
    foo(ActivityCommon common) {
        common.doSomething();
    }
}
```

...and/or use a common base class, which looks very similar:

```
class ActivityBase extends Activity { // Or whatever the base should be
    abstract void doSomething();
}

class ThisActivity extends ActivityBase {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is ThisActivity's doSomething");
    }
}

class ThatActivity extends ActivityBase {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is ThatActivity's doSomething");
    }
}

class Strawberry {
    foo(ActivityBase activity) {
        activity.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: i need it use like this `foo(MainActivity thisVariable )`  `foo(DiffActivity thisVariable )` `foo(nextActivity thisVariable )`

Comment: @LukášŠálek: You'll want to put the common aspects in an interface, see the updated answer.

Comment: @Blobonat: Pretty sure not, from the text in the question and the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show the rudimentary approach of Object as you seem to be unaware of how Java works. You can use Generics as well but it will go over your head and you will blunder around before actually understanding how it works.

```
foo(Object passedActivity){
   //Object is the base class to all classes in java and can refer to anything

   if(passedActivity instanceof FirstActivity){
      FirstActivity fref = (FirstActivity)passedActivity;
      //modify the data now using fref
      //fref.finish(); or any other similar thing

   }else if(passedActivity instanceof SecondActivity){
      SecondActivity sref=(SecondActivity)passedActivity;
      //modify using sref now
      //sref.finish(); or any other similar thing
   }else{
      Log.d("Error","Please pass a valid Activity");
   }


}
```